# Can't get CVImageBufferRef in captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection?

Tags: iphone, photo

I am trying to get access to the pixel data directly after shooting an image.
Therefore I think I will need CVImageBufferRef, but its always 0x00000000 why?

```
    [stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
 {
     if(imageSampleBuffer){

         CVImageBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(imageSampleBuffer);
         CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you can't use CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer on the CMSampleBufferRef that captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection returns. So far as I can tell, it's in JPG format, and you need to tease it out with:                                                          NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];    
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
// I'm trying to find a better answer, myself

Comment: Had the same issue and your fix worked, thanks! So wierd as its how the demo code works?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the key `kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey` of the outputSettings of  `AVCaptureStillImageOutput`:

```
  _stillImageOutput = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput new];
  NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange], kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey, nil];
  [_stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];

  if ([_captureSession canAddOutput:_stillImageOutput])
    [_captureSession addOutput:_stillImageOutput];
```

There are two possible keys `(AVVideoCodecKey and kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey)` to set, but there are mutually exclusive. (On iOS 6 and later, you can also set the image quality key `AVVideoQualityKey` if you use the AVVideoCodecKey.)